# How do I query a set of objects with an array of values in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
const rankSchema = new Schema(
  {
    rank: { type: Object, default: {} },
    lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
  { minimize: false }
);
```

And my database has an object 'rank' with many other objects inside of it like this.

```
rank: {
  Person1: { Stat1: 2, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 4 },
  Person2: { Stat1: 4, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 2 },
  Person3: { Stat1: 1, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 1 },
  Person4: { Stat1: 2, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 3 }
}
```

Now I have an array of strings that contains a few of these people

`['Person1', 'Person2']`

I want to be able to find all the person objects in that array and return their stats.
So essentially the final output after using the array of strings would be

```
Person1: { Stat1: 2, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 4 },
Person2: { Stat1: 4, Stat2: 0, Stat3: 0, Stat4: 2, Stat5: 2 }
```

I tried using `$in` and various different queries but nothing seems to work and I am stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use an array for ranks instead of nested objects?

Comment: @ParthShah That would be the better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to filter your object by dynamic field names but if your parameters are known when you're building your query then it's easier to use regular [`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) and apply projection:

```
db.collection.find({},{ "rank.Person1": 1,  "rank.Person2": 1})
```

```js
let input = ['Person1', 'Person2'];
let entries = input.map(p => ([`rank.${p}`, 1]))
let projection = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(projection);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kCDulgntbp0)