# How to store an associative array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a large data set that's structured like this:

```
[
  Person1: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 },
  Person2: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 },
  Person3: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 },
]
```

My schema looks something like this:

```
const rankSchema = new Schema(
  {
    rank: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
  { minimize: false }
);
```

I have also tried:

```
{
    rank: [],
    lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
},
// and also
 {
    rank: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed },
    lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
```

But nothing I do seems to be working. I am starting to think that storing information like this is not possible so what would be the best way to structure my data so that I won't have to loop through the entire array to find a specific person.

Edit: For clarification, I am trying to store that entire data set in the "rank" value of the schema.

Comment: is that even a valid format? should it be like `[{Person1:{..}},{Person2:{..}},...]`

Comment: @KarlL Will I be be able to look up each person without having to loop through each object in the way you're talking about? I guess I'll have to find a different way if my format isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your data like this:

```
let  data = {
  Person1: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 },
  Person2: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 },
  Person3: { Mid: 0, Support: 0, Jungle: 0, Top: 0, Bot: 0 }
}
```

Then you can access it by property like:

```
data.Person1, data.Person2 ...
```

also you can just use `Object` as the `type` for 'rank' field, then you can store your data into that field directly

```
const rankSchema = new Schema(
  {
    rank: {type: Object}
    lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
  { minimize: false }
);
```

Comment: I originally had it this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772021/how-do-i-query-a-set-of-objects-with-an-array-of-values-in-mongoose/62772149#62772149)  but it made it really difficult to query each separate person and thought making it an array would be easier. I will switch back to that since it still works.

Comment: Was stuck with this same question. Thanks for your answer.